# How to Surround Links with Bounding Box Using CSS

Tags: html, css

In a responsive design website, I need to show four links presented side-by-side and have the collection of those 4 links enclosed within a self-resizing border.  If all four links can't all fit horizontally on one line without overwriting each other, those links that can't fit should drop down to subsequent lines and the bounding border box should increase in size.

My main problem is that the bounding box... doesn't surround the links or resize properly.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code and CSS that I've tried:  http://jsfiddle.net/K3jyD/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="boundingbox">
    <div class="boundeditem">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><a title="Link Number One" href="http://www.abc.com/1/"><span><strong>NUMBER ONE</strong></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boundeditem">
        <div><a title="Link Number Two" href="http://www.abc.com/2/"><span><strong>NUMBER TWO</strong></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boundeditem">
        <div><a title="Link Number Three" href="http://www.abc.com/3/"><span><strong>NUMBER THREE</strong></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boundeditem">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><a title="Link Number Four" href="http://www.abc.com/4/"><span><strong>NUMBER FOUR</strong></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.boundingbox {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    clear:both;
}

.boundeditem {
    width:25%;
    min-width:25%;
    max-width:25%;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}

.boundeditem div {
    text-align: center;
}

.boundeditem a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I am not permitted to use jquery or external javascript libraries other than plain old html and css on this project.

Comment: Quick Question, quite off topic, but why are you not "not permitted to use jquery or external javascript libraries other than plain old html and css"?

Comment: the contents of the bounding box are `floated` so if you float the bounding box as well i think you will be alright.

Comment: I can't use jquery or external javascript because the css is part of a WordPress site.  In fact, perhaps I can do it through the hosted jquery libraries via the Google CDN.  Thanks!

Comment: @melc --  Yes, it works - thank you!   For want of a nail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float:left` is bringing your links outside the bounding box. Try this instead:

```
.boundeditem {
    width:25%;
    min-width:25%;
    max-width:25%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

If you want four links next to each other rather than three, make the width slightly smaller than 25% and put the padding in the div *inside* boundeditem rather than boundeditem itself.

```
.boundeditem {
    width:24%;
    min-width:24%;
    max-width:24%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.boundeditem div {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to the .boundingbox

```
.boundingbox {
position: absolute;
height: auto;
}
```

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for.